# Let an end user connect to various data sources from an application in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server, etl, data-integration

I am currently working on an application where an end user need to be able to connect to various sources (Excel, SQL Server, Oracle, IBM, ...). The end user is then able also select a target to load the data to (SQL Server, Oracle, IBM, ...).

See it as ETL without the 'T'.

Currently I do this based on a front end GUI where the end user puts in some fields. This generates the connections string and source query. Based on this I generate an SSIS Package in .net.

This has some limitations. I always need SQL Server, also If my source is Oracle and my destionation is Oracle.

Questions:

1. Is it doable (where to start?) writing this extract and load phase
   purely in .Net?
2. SSIS is very efficient with it's memory buffers. Will performance have a great impact in .Net?

If you see other viable options please do not hesitate to propose or ask more information to be able to propose a well founded answer.

thanks in advance